# Efficient sampling of a fixed number of rows in BigQuery

Tags: random, google-bigquery

I have a large dataset of size N, and want to get a (uniformly) random sample of size n. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375456/random-sampling-in-google-bigquery) offers two possible solutions:

```
SELECT foo FROM mytable WHERE RAND() < n/N
```

→ This is fast, but doesn't give me exactly n rows (only approximately).

```
SELECT foo, RAND() as r FROM mytable ORDER BY r LIMIT n
```

→ This requires to sort N rows, which seems unnecessary and wasteful (especially if n << N).

Is there a solution that combines the advantages of both? I imagine I could use the first solution to select 2n rows, then sort this smaller dataset, but it's sort of ugly and not guaranteed to work, so I'm wondering whether there's a better option.

Comment: Second solution looks good. Wasteful in terms of time or query cost? Have you tried running the query? It depends on the data size, but such a simple query should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I compared the two queries execution times using BigQuery standard SQL with the `natality` sample dataset (137,826,763 rows) and getting a sample for `source_year` column of size *n*. The queries are executed without using cached results.

Query1:

```
SELECT source_year
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
WHERE RAND() < n/137826763
```

Query2:

```
SELECT source_year, rand() AS r
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
ORDER BY r
LIMIT n
```

Result:

```
n        Query1   Query2
1000     ~2.5s    ~2.5s
10000    ~3s      ~3s
100000   ~3s      ~4s
1000000  ~4.5s    ~15s
```

For *n <= 10<sup>5</sup>* the difference is *~ 1s* and for *n >= 10<sup>6</sup>* the execution time differ significantly. The cause seems to be that when LIMIT is added to the query, then the ORDER BY runs on multiple workers. See the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270218/resource-exceeded-error-message-in-order-by) provided by Mikhail Berlyant.

I thought your propose to combine both queries could be a possible solution. Therefore I compared the execution time for the combined query:

New Query:

```
SELECT source_year,rand() AS r
FROM (
  SELECT source_year
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
  WHERE RAND() < 2*n/137826763)
ORDER BY r
LIMIT n
```

Result:

```
n       Query1    New Query
1000    ~2.5s     ~3s
10000   ~3s       ~3s
100000  ~3s       ~3s
1000000 ~4.5s     ~6s
```

The execution time in this case vary in *<=1.5s* for *n <= 10<sup>6</sup>*. It is a good idea to select *n+some_rows* rows in the subquery instead of *2n* rows, where *some_rows* is a constant number large enough to get more than *n* rows.

Regarding what you said about “not guaranteed to work”, I understand that you are worried that the new query doesn’t retrieve exactly *n* rows. In this case, if *some_rows* is large enough, it will always get more than *n* rows in the subquery. Therefore, the query will return exactly *n* rows.

To summarize, the combined query is not so fast as Query1 but it get exactly *n* rows and it is faster than the Query2. So, it could be a solution for uniformly random samples. I want to point out that if ORDER BY is not specified, the BigQuery output is non-deterministic, which means you might receive a different result each time you execute the query. If you try to execute the following query several times without using cached results, you will got different results.

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki1B`
LIMIT 5
```

Therefore, depends on how randomly you want to have the samples, this maybe a better solution.